# Unexpected 'apply' after onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, apply, jslint

I don't know why JsLint doesn't allow me to use 'apply' after onclick event. The message says: unexpected 'apply'.

```
document.forms[0].elements['field'].onclick.apply(document.forms[0].elements['field']);
```

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I found the solution, I just need to execute the onclick event without the apply function, I tried to execute the `click()` function which is different from `onclick()` function.

```
document.forms[0].elements['field'].onclick();
```

Comment: `DOMElement.onclick` is not a function, it's a property you assign a function, which is why it doesn't have an `apply` function.

Also, I don't really get what you are trying to accomplish with this. Are you trying to manually fire a click event?

Comment: Try this `document.forms[0].elements['field'].onclick = function(){//code}`

Comment: i try to fire a click event to execute the onclick function (set in the DOM) with the same context

Comment: I find the solution, i just need to execute the onclick event, i'll update my post